# Get the current status of a test in this test

Tags: robotframework

I had a test suite that was working, composed of test cases that were either checked by SHOULD or automatically handled if *ERROR* was printed.
But I had to create a loop following a request.
I now have a loop that performs several of these same operations.

Before :
[image]
etc...

At each end of this loop, I need to know if errors were encountered or if *ERROR* was printed in the console.
I can't use '${TEST_STATUS}' anymore because it can't be called in the test itself.

Now :

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: It can't be used in the case, right, but what will happen if one of the loops fail? Say if in the 3rd out of 10 iterations a check fails, won't it once again fail the case? If so, you can continue having that check in the teardown & call the Fatal Error.

Comment: You could wrap error-prone keywords with "Run Keyword And Warn On Failure" or similar. They return True/False depending on success and you can work with that.